# optoisolator +ve polarity in - negative polarity out

Tags: power-electronics

This is an amateur application and I am just starting out with optocouplers (and electronics in general).

The optocoupler calculations in the circuit below were mirrored from an [online tutorial](http://electronicsbeliever.com/optocoupler-circuit-design-and-detailed-analysis/), except the use of Vcc -5V. I am not completely sure they are correct for the application.

However, I cannot find a specific answer to my question...

Will the circuit below work in the configuration shown. Primarily, Vdd +5V and Vcc -5V, theoretically producing an output of ~-5V? (Though the circuit would be non-inverting if both sides were +ve polarity).

Is this a correct application of an optocoupler circuit, to separate sources of different polarity. It seems like an ideal application for the device.

The thought comes to mind, that Vcc could / should be connected to +ve ground. Guessing that the output would then need to be configured as an inverting optocoupler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTTfeA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. You can indeed use a optocoupler but the photo-transistor is being reverse biased here, instead of forward-biased. The polarity of the photo-transistor side needs to be turned upside down.

So if you swap over the two connections (collector and emitter) from your photo-transistor, it'll work. This is shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2fPKX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's assuming that your generic opto-coupler has a photo-transistor that can handle the load current and that the diode current is correct, but that's not your question here.

Comment: Thanks. That's making sense. Just need to decide on a type of optocoupler.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop. The transistor in the common base application is interesting.  I will run it in a simulator.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what polarity you want.  If you want inverting, then your circuit would work if you flipped the collector and emitter of the transistor.  With 0 V in you get 0 V out.  With +5 V in, you get -5 V out.

If you want non-inverting, then reverse the transistor and resistor (after flipping the transistor to the right C-E polarity).

However, you don't need to use a opto-isolator at all since both sides are connected to the same ground.  For a non-inverting level shifter, you can use a single transistor:

[image]

This is using the transistor in the *common base* configuration.

If you really do want inverting, then it takes two transistor, although there are then various options.  Here are just two of them:

[image]